# Elasticsearch query : document match only if distance is lower than another field value

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm facing a problem with elasticsearch and I don't know how it is possible to solve it.

Here is my document :

```
{
  "company": "XXX",
  "InBusinessSince": "YYYY-MM-DD",
  "...": "...",
  "location": {
      "lat": 14.01234,
      "lon": 60.1234
  },
  "maxDistanceInKm": 50
}
```

I want to be able to query my index by passing another location as a parameter and only have in return the documents where the distance between the location of the document and the location passed in parameter is below maxDistanceInKm value.

Bonus Question : In fact if it is possible I'd like to be able to provide a location as a parameter **and** also an alternateMaxDistance, and only have documents that matches distance is lower than the minimum between maxDistanceInKm of the document and alternateMaxDistance

Note : of course it is a simplified version of my index it contains lots of other fields onto which I also apply various conditions but I have no problem for them.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Ps : I'm looking at painless script to solve this but I've never used them and I don't know if it is possible to use them for such situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the first question for now:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": """
              doc['location'].arcDistance(
                params.location.lat,
                params.location.lon
              ) * 0.001 <= doc['maxDistanceInKm'].value
            """,
            "params": {
              "location": {
                "lat": 15.5,
                "lon": 60
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Assuming the `location` field is of `geo_point` type, you can use the `arcDistance()` method to calculate, in meters(!), the distance to another point specified by lat/lon coordinates.

(Note that I used triple quotes to improve legibility; this is not valid JSON syntax, and to try it, you'll have to replace them with double quotes and keep the script source on one line.)

To include an `alternateMaxDistance` parameter, just use the `Math.min()` method:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": """
              doc['location'].arcDistance(
                params.location.lat,
                params.location.lon
              ) * 0.001 <= Math.min(
                doc['maxDistanceInKm'].value,
                params.alternateMaxDistance
              )
            """,
            "params": {
              "location": {
                "lat": 15.5,
                "lon": 60
              },
              "alternateMaxDistance": 170
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For completion, here's how you'd use this query from Spring Data Elasticsearch.

Assuming a POJO/entity like:

```
@Document(createIndex = false, indexName = "so77843318")
class CompanyDetails {

  @Id
  @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
  private String company;

  // GeoPointField and GeoPoint under org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.*
  @GeoPointField
  private GeoPoint location;

  @Field(type = FieldType.Half_Float)
  private Float maxDistanceInKm;

  //... accessors, etc.
}
```

and a Spring-based setup with an `ElasticsearchRestTemplate` injected in your service (or repository, etc.), one basic way to execute the query is:

```
List<SearchHit<CompanyDetails>> queryAround(
  org.elasticsearch.common.geo.GeoPoint location,
  Float alternateMaxDistance
) {

  final var filterBuilder = boolQuery().filter(
    scriptQuery(
      new Script(
        ScriptType.INLINE,
        "painless",
        """
            doc['location'].arcDistance(
              params.location.lat,
              params.location.lon
            ) * 0.001 <= Math.min(
              doc['maxDistanceInKm'].value,
              params.alternateMaxDistance
            )
          """,
        Map.of("location", location, "alternateMaxDistance", alternateMaxDistance)
      )
    )
  );

  final var queryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withTrackTotalHits(true) // if we need the total hits number, ES 7+
    .withQuery(filterBuilder);

  return elasticsearch.search(
    queryBuilder.build(),
    CompanyDetails.class,
    IndexCoordinates.of("so77843318")
  ).getSearchHits();
}
```

Note that:

- You must still convert individual SearchHit<?> instances to `CompanyDetails` instances via this method, and you might want to keep the index name used in `IndexCoordinates.of("so77843318")` in a property, etc.
- You could use other queries (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/reference/elasticsearch/template.html#elasticsearch.operations.queries), more straightforward from a coding point of view; I am used to the `NativeSearchQuery`, which is quite flexible.
- In general, script-based queries might become a performance liability, depending on various factors; check out https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/scripts-and-search-speed.html and keep those things in mind: what Elasticsearch already optimizes, what you can optimize more, etc. (e.g., maybe use a stored script?)

Comment: Thank you Octavian !

Now I need to figure out how I can process this solution with spring-data-elasticsearch.

But knowing that it is achievable with ElasticSearch is the first big step for me.

Thanks again :)

Comment: You're welcome. I amended the answer to include a Spring Data Elasticsearch code sample, I hope it'll help you. Bon courage ! ;)

Comment: Thanks again Octavian, for the Spring Data Elasticsearch part, I managed to do this by storing the script and use the stored script by its id in my request

Comment: Indeed, that's probably the best approach.

Comment: Regarding the performance I wonder if it may be best to split the distance condition into 2 differents must query instead of using a script.
I don't know if there would be a huge difference on response times.

It may be something to dig in the future on my side :)

Comment: Well, you could compute and query based a runtime field (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/runtime.html)/script field (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/search-fields.html#script-fields), but I am not sure it'll help that much... You still need to perform the computation, you just don't query via a script.